# Displaying key/pair data

Tags: apex, soql, data, array

I have four objects which allow me to record events, rsvp contacts attending the event and store any additional details for each given event.

My schema is as follows:

```
Contact (Id, Name) <-- Standard object
Event (Id, Title)
EventRSVP (rsvpID, Contact.ID, Event.ID)
EventData (Id, rsvpID, Key, Value)
```

Now the reason I have designed a key/value object is because each event may need to hold different details, please check example rows below:

```
User    Event   Key     Value
-------------------------------
Bob     Event1  Cheese  true
Bob     Event1  Lettuce true
Bob     Event1  Mayo    false
Dave    Event1  Cheese  true
Dave    Event1  Lettuce true
Dave    Event1  Mayo    true
Bob     Event2  Brakes  'low'
Bob     Event2  Oil     'full'
Bob     Event2  Washer  'low'
```

Now I would like to display the following data as follows:

```
User    Key1    Key2    Key3
-----------------------------
Bob     Value1  Value2  Value3
Dave    Value1  Value3  Value3
```

I am only interested in making a list for 'Event 1' and its keys so I can hard code the keys/columns if easier.

I know this could be done via SQL but I believe SOQL will not, so I believe the only option is to create an array derived from the SOQL to do this?

I have started a really basic apex to fetch all rows but I'm not sure where to go from there

```
public with sharing class eventlist {

    public list<EventData__c> eventItems {get;set;}

    public list<EventData__c> getRSVPData(){
        eventItems = new list<EventData__c>();

        String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Key__c, Value__c FROM EventData__c ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC';

        eventItems = Database.query(query);
        return eventItems;
    }

}
```

Comment: One option will be to create a map of maps. The top level map would be keyed by the User. The inner map would be keyed by the keys and would then contain the value for that user. I think I've seen other questions dealing with this and examples of displaying this data in a Visualforce page.

Comment: Check it out: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm